# If $F(x) = f(xf(xf(x)))$, find $F '(1)$.

Tags: derivatives

If $F(x) = f(xf(xf(x))),$ where $f(1) = 2, f(2) = 3, f '(1) = 3, f '(2) = 4,$ and $f '(3) = 5,$ find $F '(1)$.

$F '(1) =$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Chain Rule,

$$F'(x) = f'(x f(x f(x) ) ) \cdot [ f(x f(x) ) + x f'(x f(x) )(x f'(x)+f(x) )]$$

Thus,

$$F'(1) = f'(3)( f(2) + f'(2)( f'(1) +f(1) )) = 115 $$

fill in details.